# Is it possible to set day cell content html in a Fullcalendar resourceTimelineWeek view?

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

I want to add button to each cell . `slotLaneContent` not adding button to each cell. Only one row shows buttons. `dayRender` method is not working on FullCalendar v5.

Comment: Why on earth do you need to add a button to each cell? What's wrong with using select or dateClick?

Comment: UI design require this feature

Comment: Does it, though? Why? Just because someone specified it doesn't mean it's the best way to do it. Specifications can be changed. What is the purpose of these buttons?